# Weird behavior in mariadb table with unique key defined (ie, not so unique)

Tags: mariadb

I'm trying to export/import a BD from one system to another but the import fails with the following error:

```
ERROR 1062 (23000) at line 8232: Duplicate entry '0-3-30168717-com_liferay_product_navigation_product_menu_web_...' for key 'IX_C7057FF7'
```

That table is defined as such:

```
CREATE TABLE `PortletPreferences` (
  `portletPreferencesId` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `ownerId` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ownerType` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `plid` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `portletId` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `preferences` longtext DEFAULT NULL,
  `mvccVersion` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `companyId` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`portletPreferencesId`),
  UNIQUE KEY `IX_C7057FF7` (`ownerId`,`ownerType`,`plid`,`portletId`),
```

In the mysql dump file, I see these two entries:

```
(31453178,0,3,30168717,'com_liferay_product_navigation_product_menu_web_portlet_ProductMenuPortlet','<portlet-preferences />',0,10132)
(31524539,0,3,30168717,'com_liferay_product_navigation_product_menu_web_portlet_ProductMenuPortlet','<portlet-preferences />',0,10132)
```

So, yep, there are two entries with the same unique key. How is that possible?!?

Knowing this, I ran the following select statement against the source DB:

```
select portletPreferencesId, ownerId, ownerType, plid, portletId from PortletPreferences where ownerId = 0 AND ownerType = 3 AND plid = 30168717 AND portletId like 'com_liferay_product_navigation_product_menu_web%';
```

And it outputs just ONE LINE!

```
+----------------------+---------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| portletPreferencesId | ownerId | ownerType | plid | portletId |
+----------------------+---------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 31524539 | 0 | 3 | 30168717 | com_liferay_product_navigation_product_menu_web_portlet_ProductMenuPortlet |
+----------------------+---------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

By the `portletPreferencesId` field, it outputs the second entry in the dump file. So I did one more select for the other row as such:

```
select portletPreferencesId, ownerId, ownerType, plid, portletId from PortletPreferences where portletPreferencesId = 31453178;
```

And I get:

```
+----------------------+---------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| portletPreferencesId | ownerId | ownerType | plid | portletId |
+----------------------+---------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 31453178 | 0 | 3 | 30168717 | com_liferay_product_navigation_product_menu_web_portlet_ProductMenuPortlet |
+----------------------+---------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

My question is, what's going on?!? Why is that entry not output by the first select statement and why is it there in the first place if those fields were supposed to be unique???

I have a bad feeling about the state of the source database :-( Oh, and that's just one. I have multiple duplicate keys like that in that table :-(

Thanks

Comment: A lazy way of fixing, assuming that all the duplicate are in fact entire rows that are identical, is to mysqldump with `--insert-ignore`, or edit the existing SQL file replacing `INSERT` with `INSERT IGNORE`

Answer (score 0):

There are occasional bugs like [MDEV-15250](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-15250) that can cause duplicate entries to occur.

Sometimes you may not see these as parts of the optimizer expect only a single row because of the unique constraint so won't search beyond it. Maybe a query across a range including the entries would be more likely to show it (which is what mysqldump would have done).

If you don't think its related to `ALTER TABLE` occurring at the same time as insertions (like MDEV-15250), and have a good hunch as the set of operations on the table that may have escaped the unique key enforcement, can you please create a [bug report](https://jira.mariadb.org).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. The MDEV-15250 bug seems to be caused by a master/slave timing issue. My database is not in this situation. We're not sure when it started but we'll try to clean the offending rows and see if it happens again. If it does, I'll open a bug report.